# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, lnk2019

I've searched and searched for hours and can't seem to find a fix for this.

I'm building a linked list, and tested it as a type    int and everything worked perfectly, now after I've converted it to a class template it's come up with this.

Hopefully some other eyes can see what I'm missing. I've cleaned and rebuilt too.
Ps I also tried switching the linker system from console to windows and it actually bought up more errors.

Here is an example Error:

> Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall    LinkedList::LinkedList(void)" (??0?$LinkedList@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced    in function _main    D:\...\Source.obj  Text-LinkedList

LinkedList.h

```
            #pragma once

            //***********************************************************
            // Author: Blake McLeod
            //
            // This class specifies the members to implement the basic
            // properties of a linked list.
            //***********************************************************
            #include <iostream>
            #include "Node.h"
            using namespace std;

            template <class T>
            class LinkedList
            {
            public:
                            //default constructor
                            //Initializes the list to an empty state.
                            //Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0;
                            LinkedList();

                            //copy constructor
                            LinkedList(const LinkedList<T> &otherList);

                            //destructor
                            //Deletes all the nodes from the list.
                            //Postcondition: The list object is destroyed.
                            ~LinkedList();

                            //Function to delete all the nodes from the list.
                            //Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0;
                            void destroy();

                            //Function to determine whether the list is empty.
                            //Postcondition: Returns true if the list is empty, otherwise
                            // it returns false.
                            bool isEmpty() const;

                            //Function to output the data contained in each node.
                            //Postcondition: none
                            void print() const;

                            //Function to return the number of nodes in the list.
                            //Postcondition: The value of count is returned.
                            int getLength() const;

                            //Function to return the first element of the list.
                            //Precondition: The list must exist and must not be empty.
                            //Postcondition: If the list is empty, the program terminates;
                            // otherwise, the first element of the list is returned.
                            T firstNode() const;

                            //Function to return the last element of the list.
                            //Precondition: The list must exist and must not be empty.
                            //Postcondition: If the list is empty, the program
                            //  terminates; otherwise, the last
                            // element of the list is returned.
                            T lastNode() const;

                            //Function to determine whether searchItem is in the list.
                            //Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is in the list,
                            // otherwise the value false is returned.
                            bool search(const T &searchItem) const;

                            //Function to insert newItem in the list.
                            //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem
                            // is inserted at the proper place in the list, and
                            // count is incremented by 1.
                            void insert(const T &newItem);

                            //Function to insert newItem at the beginning of the list.
                            //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is
                            // inserted at the beginning of the list, last points to
                            // the last node in the list, and count is incremented by
                            // 1.
                            void insertFirst(const T &newItem);

                            //Function to insert newItem at the end of the list.
                            //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is
                            // inserted at the end of the list, last points to the
                            // last node in the list, and count is incremented by 1.
                            void insertLast(const T &newItem);

                            //Function to delete deleteItem from the list.
                            //Postcondition: If found, the node containing deleteItem is
                            // deleted from the list. first points to the first node,
                            // last points to the last node of the updated list, and
                            // count is decremented by 1.
                            void deleteNode(const T &deleteItem);

                            //Function to make a copy of otherList.
                            //Postcondition: A copy of otherList is created and assigned
                            // to this list.
                            void copyList(const LinkedList<T> &otherList);

                            //Overload the assignment operator.
                            const LinkedList<T>& operator= (const LinkedList<T> &otherList);

            private:
                            int length;                                 //Length of linked list
                            Node<T> *head;                   //Pointer to first node
                            Node<T> *trailer;                       //Pointer to last node
                            Node<T> *current;           //Pointer to current node
            };
```

LinkedList.cpp

```
            //***********************************************************
            // Author: Blake McLeod
            //
            // This file defines all function members of the LinkedList.h
            // class file, functions are designed to handle various basic
            // tasks required to manage a linked list.
            //***********************************************************
            #include "LinkedList.h"
            #include <iostream>
            #include <vector>
            #include <string>
            using namespace std;

            //default constructor
            //Initializes the list to an empty state.
            //Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0;
            template <class T>
            LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
            {
                            head = NULL;
                            trailer = NULL;
                            length = 0;

                            cout << "Created an empty linked list object." << endl;
            }

            //copy constructor
            template <class T>
            LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList<T> &otherList)
            {
                            head = NULL;
                            copyList(otherList);
            }

            //destructor
            //Deletes all the nodes from the list.
            //Postcondition: The list object is destroyed.
            template <class T>
            LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
            {
                            //Clear all elements in linked list
                            destroy();
            }

            //Function to delete all the nodes from the list.
            //Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0;
            template <class T>
            void LinkedList<T>::destroy()
            {
                            Node<T> *temp;

                            while (head)
                            {
                                            temp = head;
                                            head = head->link;
                                            delete temp;
                            }

                            trailer = NULL;
                            length = 0;
            }

            //Function to determine whether the list is empty.
            //Postcondition: Returns true if the list is empty, otherwise
            // it returns false.
            template <class T>
            bool LinkedList<T>::isEmpty() const
            {
                            return (head == NULL);
            }

            //Function to output the data contained in each node.
            //Postcondition: none
            template <class T>
            void LinkedList<T>::print() const
            {
                            Node<T> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
                            current = head; //set current point to the first node

                            while (current != NULL) //while more data to print
                            {
                                            cout << current->data << " ";
                                            current = current->link;
                            }
            }

            //Function to return the number of nodes in the list.
            //Postcondition: The value of count is returned.
            template <class T>
            int LinkedList<T>::getLength() const
            {
                            return length;
            }

            //Function to return the first element of the list.
            //Precondition: The list must exist and must not be empty.
            //Postcondition: If the list is empty, the program terminates;
            // otherwise, the first element of the list is returned.
            template <class T>
            T LinkedList<T>::firstNode() const
            {
                            if (head != NULL)
                                            return head->data;
                            else
                                            return 0;
            }

            //Function to return the last element of the list.
            //Precondition: The list must exist and must not be empty.
            //Postcondition: If the list is empty, the program
            //  terminates; otherwise, the last
            // element of the list is returned.
            template <class T>
            T LinkedList<T>::lastNode() const
            {
                            if (trailer != NULL)
                                            return trailer->data;
                            else
                                            return 0;
            }

            //Function to determine whether searchItem is in the list.
            //Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is in the list,
            // otherwise the value false is returned.
            template <class T>
            bool LinkedList<T>::search(const T &searchItem) const
            {
                            bool found = false;
                            Node<T> *current;

                            current = head;

                            while (current != NULL && !found)
                            {
                                            if (current->data >= searchItem)
                                                            found = true;
                                            else
                                                            current = current->link;
                            }

                            if (found)
                                            found = (current->data == searchItem);

                            return found;
            }

            //Function to insert newItem in the list.
            //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem
            // is inserted at the proper place in the list, and
            // count is incremented by 1.
            template <class T>
            void LinkedList<T>::insert(const T &newItem)
            {
                            Node<T> *current = NULL;
                            Node<T> *trailCurrent = NULL;
                            Node<T> *newNode = NULL;

                            bool found;

                            newNode = new Node<T>;
                            newNode->data = newItem;
                            newNode->link = NULL;

                            if (head == NULL)
                            {
                                            head = newNode;
                                            trailer = newNode;
                                            length++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                            current = head;
                                            found = false;

                                            while (current != NULL && !found)
                                            {
                                                            if (current->data >= newItem)
                                                                            found = true;
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                            trailCurrent = current;
                                                                            current = current->link;
                                                            }
                                            }

                                            if (current == head)
                                            {
                                                            newNode->link = head;
                                                            head = newNode;
                                                            length++;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                            trailCurrent->link = newNode;
                                                            newNode->link = current;

                                                            if (current == NULL)
                                                                            trailer = newNode;

                                                            length++;
                                            }
                            }

            }

            //Function to delete deleteItem from the list.
            //Postcondition: If found, the node containing deleteItem is
            // deleted from the list. first points to the first node,
            // last points to the last node of the updated list, and
            // count is decremented by 1.
            template <class T>
            void LinkedList<T>::deleteNode(const T &deleteItem)
            {
                            Node<T> *current = NULL;
                            Node<T> *trailCurrent = NULL;
                            bool found;

                            if (head == NULL) //if list is empty
                                            cout << "Error: Cannot delete node from an empty list." << endl;
                            else
                            {
                                            current = head;
                                            found = false;

                                            while (current != NULL && !found) //search list
                                            {
                                                            if (current->data >= deleteItem)
                                                                            found = true;
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                            trailCurrent = current;
                                                                            current = current->link;
                                                            }
                                            }

                                            if (current == NULL)
                                                            cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the list." << endl;
                                            else if (current->data == deleteItem)
                                            {
                                                            if (head == current)
                                                            {
                                                                            head = head->link;
                                                                            if (head == NULL)
                                                                                            trailer = NULL;

                                                                            delete current;
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                            trailCurrent->link = current->link;

                                                                            if (current == trailer)
                                                                                            trailer = trailCurrent;

                                                                            delete current;
                                                            }
                                                            length--;
                                            }
                                            else
                                                            cout << "Error: Item was not found in the list." << endl;
                            }
            }

            //Function to make a copy of otherList.
            //Postcondition: A copy of otherList is created and assigned
            // to this list.
            template <class T>
            void LinkedList<T>::copyList(const LinkedList<T> &otherList)
            {
                            Node<T> *newNode, *currentNode;

                            //ensure this list is empty
                            if (head != NULL)
                                            destroy();

                            //if otherList is empty, create empty list
                            if (otherList.head == NULL)
                            {
                                            head = NULL;
                                            trailer = NULL;
                                            length = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                            currentNode = otherList.head;
                                            length = otherList.length;

                                            head = new Node<T>; //create first node
                                            head->data = currentNode->data; //copy data
                                            head->link = NULL; //set the link field of the node to NULL
                                            trailer = head; //make last point to the head node
                                            currentNode = currentNode->link; //make currentNode point to the next node

                                            while (currentNode != NULL)
                                            {
                                                            newNode = new Node<T>; //create a node
                                                            newNode->data = currentNode->data; //copy the info
                                                            newNode->link = NULL; //set the link of newNode to NULL
                                                            trailer->link = newNode; //attach newNode after last
                                                            trailer = newNode; //make last point to the actual last node
                                                            currentNode = currentNode->link; //make currentNode point to the next node
                                            }
                            }
            }

            //Overload the assignment operator.
            template <class T>
            const LinkedList<T>& LinkedList<T>::operator= (const LinkedList<T> &otherList)
            {
                            if (this != &otherList)
                            {
                                            copyList(otherList);
                            }
                            return *this;
            }
```

Source.cpp

```
            //**********************************************************
            // Author: D.S. Malik
            //
            // This program tests the various operations on an ordered
            // linked list.
            //**********************************************************
            #include <iostream>
            #include "LinkedList.h"
            using namespace std;

            int main()
            {
                            LinkedList<int> list1, list2;
                            int num;
                            cout << "Line 7: Enter numbers ending with -999." << endl;
                            cin >> num;

                            while (num != -999)
                            {
                                            list1.insert(num);
                                            cin >> num;
                            }
                            cout << endl;

                            cout << "Line 15: list1: ";
                            list1.print();
                            cout << endl;

                            list2 = list1;
                            cout << "Line 19: list2: ";
                            list2.print();
                            cout << endl;

                            cout << "Line 22: Enter the number to be deleted: ";
                            cin >> num;
                            cout << endl;

                            list2.deleteNode(num);
                            cout << "Line 26: After deleting " << num << ", list2: " << endl;

                            list2.print();
                            cout << endl;

                            system("pause");
                            return 0;
            }
```

Sorry for the massive code, but hopefully more information will help.

Comment: Wow, that fixed it thanks!

For future readers, I moved all my function members into the header file and ensured my Linker system was set to console again and it worked first go.

Was strange how VS2013 intellisense didn't alert me to any of this.

Comment: IntelliSense is helpless, when it comes to templates.

Comment: @Blake intellisense doesn't check for linker errors, just syntax errors.

Comment: @dwcanillas That would make sense now, thanks for that.